# "Do you really want to quit?" Unity Mac OSX Prompt unwanted

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

Im building a Unity game for windows and mac.

They both have the same codebase and little to nothing changes between the Windows and OSX versions of the game.

On OSX every time I quit the game it gives me a "Do you really want to quit?" message which is presented to the user before "OnApplicationQuit" is even called in any script..

I want to get rid of this message, If I want to display a message for quit it would definitely be a better message than "Do you really want to quit?"

Has anyone else come across this issue and is there some way to fix it ??

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

the only thing I have found to override this is a native plugin to override the window close event and send -[NSApplication terminate:] instead. Which may work for my needs right now, but it is likely to create a whole new avenue of issues later on.

Comment: You should submit this to Unity as a bug/feature request. There doesn't seem to be any reason they couldn't add a bool parameter to Application.Quit that turns off the confirmation.

Comment: Its not part of application.quit, its actually worse. Press close on the mac app and it still triggers the are you sure dialog.

Comment: Never saw this message. I'm using Application.Quit() as well. Works on osx without any issues.

Comment: Even adding this to player settings would be nice. Make it a toggle followed by the desired text

Comment: As @Alex notes, I never saw this either, maybe removed from newer versions?